# Activating Windows License on Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base AMI EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, windows-server-2019

I launched a new EC2 instance using the **Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base AMI**. However whenever I go into settings it complains that "You need to activate Windows before you can personalize your PC".

How do I activate Windows on this EC2 Instance?

Answer (score -2):

Not seeing that problem with this image

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07WTRJXKS